# iPhone app incorrect autoresizing on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, autoresize

I have developed iPhone app. When i try to run this app in iPad simulator, it doesn't show me 1x/2x zoom button but application autoresize view in wrong way.

I don't want to make ipad native nibs/views so i need to disable autoresing the application.

Can somebody help?

EDIT: In 'Summary' tab, is 'iPhone' selected in the Devices drop-down menu.

EDIT2: When starting application, splash screen loads correnctly in small 1x window, than when firt view loads it switches to full screen.

[image: ipad simulator screenshot]

Comment: have you tried on a real ipad? sometimes the simulator has strange behaviour.

Comment: Yes (iPad2/iPad v.3, booth with iOS 6.0.1). It's the same as in simulator

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Target's settings, 'Summary' tab, and choose 'iPhone' instead of 'Universal' in the Devices drop-down menu.

Comment: That was first thing i checked. There is iPhone selected in devices

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or nibs?

Comment: Hi NikosM. I'm using nibs. It's older project. Now i'm making new version with XCode 4.5.

Comment: When creating a new nib, are you sure that you're selecting iPhone in the devices type? Then, are the dimensions set for iPhone in the nib's size inspector? It might be worth creating a new project and starting over again by adding one nib at a time.

Comment: I can't start new project. Because its very huge now. I tried to remove all 4 Tabs from application. Then add one tab only with one navigation controller and one view controller with xib file. It's always the same. It looks like problem is somewhere in mainWindow.xib. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Go in your Application-Info.plist and check if there is something with iPad.
On a project, I started with doing an app Universal, only developped the iPhone theme. Then, to show to the client a pre-version, I tested on an iPad and the screen was quite reverse (iPhone : Portrait mode, iPad Landscape). I figured that in the Info.plis there was still the iPad : Landscape. Maybe something like that.

Comment: There is nothing with iPad in Info.plist.